# Overwrite DS.Store ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have some code that needs to run on `store.init`.

I tried extending the default store in `app/store.js`, ember-cli seems to pick it up as a store, but the object in `this.store` is not a store

My store definition:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Store.extend({
  init:function(){
    console.log('watatLoL')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to Peter Wagenet, this has changed in Ember Data beta 19. If you're using that version or later, the file is now `app/stores/application.js` (or `app/application/store.js` if you're using pods).

Overwriting the store is the same, only the file name/location has changed. If you're using a version of Ember Data lower than beta 19, you can use the old `app/store.js` file.

---

I know this is old, but I had to answer this for another question, so I figured I would update this. By default, the Ember-CLI resolver will look for `app/store.js`, so you can declare your overridden store there.

```
// app/store.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Store.extend({
    init: function() {
        console.log('Using custom store!');
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: no worries, i remember when doing this it through an error, will test and select the correct answer when i do thanks :)

Comment: As of beta.19, the correct location is now `app/stores/application.js` (or `app/application/store.js` if you're using pods).

Answer (score 7):

The answer for **> Ember 1.13**:

The [Store](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html) now [extends the `Service`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.3.0/addon/-private/system/store.js#L211) so we can just create the `app/services/store.js` and put the following code to extend/customize the store:

```
// app/services/store.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Store.extend({

  init: function() {
    console.log('Using custom store!');
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

### Here's a sample twiddle

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd been struggling trying to figure out how to do this on newer Ember versions, all the SO answers I could find were for older implementations. This works for me as of Ember 2.16.2

Comment: Glad to help out mate :)