# EmberJS set defaultValue from parent's model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I need to set `defaultValue` of price attribute to the price of item. I don't want use ComputedProperty because when my item's price is change, my transaction_detail's price is changed too, and my scenario is set `price` value on the first time & shouldn't changed.

Here is my TransactionDetail.js.

```
var TransactionDetail = DS.Model.extend({
  transaction: DS.belongsTo('transaction'),
  item: DS.belongsTo('item', { async: true }),
  borrowed_at: borrowedAt,
  max_returned_at: maxReturnedAt,
  returned_at: DS.attr('date'),
  price: DS.attr('number', {
    defaultValue: function( detail) {
      return detail.get('item.price'); // EXPECT TO GET ITEM'S PRICE, BUT ACTUAL IS NULL
    }
  }),
});
```

And below is my Item.js

```
var Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  is_available: DS.attr('boolean', { defaultValue: true }),
  price: DS.attr('number', { defaultValue: 0 })
});
```

**UPDATE:**
After I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493561/overwrite-ds-store-ember-cli), I add file on `initializers/reopen-store.js` and edit content as below:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export function initialize(container, application) {
  var store = container.lookup('store:main');

  store.reopen({
    createRecord: function(type, properties) {
      if (type === 'transactionDetail') {
        if (typeof properties.price !== 'number') {
          properties.price = properties.item.get('price');
        }
      }

      return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }.on('createRecord')
  });

};

export default DS.Store.extend({
  name: 'reopen-store',
  initialize: initialize
});
```

but when I do `debugger;` on model, `this.get('item.price')` still `undefined`. Any idea?

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks GJK for your response. But your answer still no luck for me.
Here is my `app/store.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Store.extend({
    init: function() {
        console.log('Init called!');
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    createRecord: function(type, properties) {
      console.log('Prepare createRecord!');
      debugger;

      if (type === 'transactionDetail') {
        if (typeof properties.price !== 'number') {
          properties.price = properties.item.get('price');
        }
      }

      return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

In my console, the output just `Init called!`. No `'Prepare createRecord!'` and `debugger` is not triggered in my Chrome. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In your `defaultValue` function, `item.price` is coming up `null` because the `item` relationship likely hasn't been initialized yet. Personally, I would take care of this in the store when you create the record, not in the model.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    createRecord: function(type, properties) {
        if (type === 'transactionDetail') {
            if (typeof properties.price !== 'number') {
                properties.price = properties.item.get('price');
            }
        }

        return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

A bit more error checking is probably required, but you get the idea. If the price isn't given at the time of creation, fill it in and let the store handle the rest.

Comment: I use ember-cli, and I confused where I should create this file?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493561/overwrite-ds-store-ember-cli/26607584#26607584).

Comment: Hmm still no luck for me. See my `update 2` question as detail.