# can I create custom ember-data methods?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm wondering if there's any way for me to create a custom ember-data method so I can do things like this:

`this.store.customMethod('klass')`

I know I can override the existing methods for my needs but I need more control than that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely what you want to do is add a custom methods to your models adapter if you want to do custom things. So in `adapters/klass.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  customMethod(){
    const data = {user: {email: this.get('email')}};
    const baseUrl = this.urlForFindAll('user');
    return Ember.$.post(`${baseUrl}/password`, data);
  }
});
```

Then somewhere else:

```
const adapter = this.store.adapterFor('user');
adapter.customMethod();
```

But yeah sure you can extend the store. In `stores/application.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Store.extend({
    customMethod(model) {
      // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: I have extended `Store` with a custom function but it doesn't get called. Did something changed in `ember-data 2.2.1`?

Comment: This answer is deprecated in Ember 1.13+ (see user634545's answer below)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to implement a custom store service.

```
// app/services/store.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Store.extend({

  init: function() {
    console.log('Using custom store!');
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }

});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34999549/634545