# What is the proper way to store persistent variables in Ember RESTAdapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Sometimes you want a variable that is persistent as long as the page is not reloaded. Since a lot of the Ember convention is extending objects, I'm not sure where to put private variables so that they are accessible from public functions.

It seems obvious to just put it in the `extend()`ed object, but then the variable isn't reachable from within a function in that same object, probably because Ember doesn't `bind()` the parent object to the function.

Here's an example of how I store an array so that I can deduct if my `RESTAdapter` should reload a record that has been requested before:

```
shouldReloadRecord: function(store, snapArray) {

    window.recordHashStore = window.recordHashStore || [];
    let recordHash  = `${snapArray.modelName}/${snapArray.id}?include=${snapArray.include}`;
    if (!~window.recordHashStore.indexOf(recordHash)) {
        window.recordHashStore.push(recordHash);
        console.log('Reloading', snapArray.type);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        console.log('NOT reloading', snapArray.type);
        return false;
    }
}
```

the relevant code here is `window.recordHashStore = window.recordHashStore || []`. This does exactly what I want, but it doesn't look very Ember'y. Also it's not nice to use the `window` global scope. Where can I store private variables for the duration of the app in the browser, so that it's available and not overwritten on transitions?

Comment: Why are you using an array here? Using an object will be less code and O(1) instead of O(n). I second using a service for the data, even if it is trivial.

Comment: @PatrickFisher it's a quick solution that came to mind, because I was thinking about adding cache as records in the DS store. It's not relevant for the question though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a good use case for an [Ember.Service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/applications/services/). A Service is essentially a singleton, but it isn't exposed in your `window`/global scope. It also isn't affected by route transitions (unless you have code that manipulates a service on route transition).

You can inject your service into your RESTAdapter, and store the state in the service.

Comment: Upvoted. A service for a single array seems a bit much. Isn't there a global function, like this? (I completely made this up): `DS.store.addToSet('recordHashStore', recordHash)`

Comment: @Redsandro there is not, but you could try adding those methods by extending the Store. (Apparently the Store extends Ember.Service too!) See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34999549/1112407

Comment: If it´s just a variable like a host url or something you could simple define that in app.js like App.variable= value; and import it anywhere, but don´t use it for larger amounts